# How to share a public key on a Flask endpoint in Python for client-side encryption?

Tags: python, flask, rsa, endpoint

I'm developing a server using Flask in Python, and I need to share a public key with clients so they can encrypt data before sending it to the server.

I've implemented an endpoint using Flask that should return the public key to the client.

```
#SERVER
def generate_key_pair(size, public_e):
    private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        public_exponent=public_e,
        key_size=size,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    public_key = private_key.public_key()
    return private_key, public_key



private_key, public_key = generate_key_pair(size = 2048, public_e = 65537)

@app.route('/bob_publickey', methods=['GET'])
def get_val():
    pem_public_key = export_public_key_to_pem(public_key)
    return jsonify({"publickey": pem_public_key.decode("utf-8")})
```

The clients should use this public key to encrypt data before sending it to the server. I've successfully set up an endpoint in Flask that provides the public key, but I'm unsure about how to receiving and utilizing this key on the client side.

My question is about the best way to implement this functionality.
Thank you in advance for any advice or suggestions!

Comment: Is https insufficient?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and your attention. The reason I am proceeding with this implementation is related to a specific study I am conducting. My goal is to demonstrate the feasibility of a Chosen Ciphertext Attack (CCA) under certain operational conditions.

Comment: For the client, get the key, store it, and use it to encrypt the body of each request before sending to the server. Then the server decrypts the request body before handling it.

Comment: Questions about specific problems in code tend to get higher quality answers on [so] than open-ended questions or questions about the best way to do something, best library, etc.